Hosting strategies for python django rest api very light weight applications in production environment?
I am currently hosting python web services on apache server with mod_wsgi in daemon mode. Everything is fine until, I have added a new virtualhost or changed existing virtualhost because when I have changed existing virtualhost or added new virtualhost the apache server will not recognize it directly without reloading or restarting.
So when I do a graceful restart or reload of apache server to recognize new configuration all other currently requests processing daemons of mod_wsgi getting terminated forcefully as graceful is not supported by managed processes of apache server whereas mod_wsgi is a managed process.
So, when I am changing configuration of one python web service I am facing downtime as well as forceful termination of other ongoing requests. So, the above situation is not good in the production environment.
At same time I want to host more no.of like around more than 200 and less than 300 very light weight python django web services
I am currently following the apache server + mod_wsgi in daemon mode in the development environment but I know that it is not good or suitable for the production environment as I cannot afford the downtime of other ongoing requests.
I want to know if there are any other hosting strategies in which the above solutions will be resolved and also I want to deploy a large no.of very lightweight python django applications in production environment.
I know there will be strategies with containers and containers orchestration platforms but I want to know is there anything without containers?

So, when I am changing configuration of one python web services I am facing downtime as well forceful termination of other ongoing requests. So, the above situation is not good in production environment.  You have one server. Don't do that. Use multiple servers, and remove a server from the pool and drain connections first.
